# Что значит клас header в css, если он не прописан нигде в html коде?

Tags: css

Что значит клас header в css, если он не прописан нигде в html коде?

```
.header {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.header h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ODfUUTEJ9f 
Вот. код из урока в ютубе

Comment: @Yuli Ka, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Если он не прописан в html коде это значит

1. что когда-то там была шапка сайта и забыли почистить css
2. шапка имеет другое имя класса
3. если есть другие страницы посмотрите их, может быть на этих страницах есть потерянная шапка
4. покажите ссылку на сайт

**.header** - так в основном называют класс для шапки сайта

Comment: Забыли написать о моральной составляющей удаление хедера =)